# Reordering in Windows Phone 8.1 ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 `ListView`. I want to reorder the items in the `ListView`.I want to initiate the reorder mode on longpress, I can manage it by tapping in to the items `Holding` event and change the `ListView`s `ReorderMode` to `Enabled`. The `ListView` looks like this

[image]

**1. Is there a way to "select" and item as ready to be dragged?** So the `ListView` looks like this? I could not find any property or anything to make it "selected". It would be much better for the user to have the item he initiates the reorder on selected.

[image]

**2. Is there a way to know the user dropped the item to another places (did the reorder)?** I thought I could accomplish it by using the `DragOver` or `DragLeaving` events on the ListView, but they are fired when the reorder mode is disabled, not when the item is dropped to another position.

**3. Is there a way to make the gaps between the items in reorder mode smaller?** I found the `ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset` resource but changing it (directly or editing a style for `ListViewItem`) does not make any change.

Comment: As for the **2.** - maybe you can try to make use of *ListView.Items.VectorChanged* event - once the user reorders any item, the event is fired twice, once for removal and once for insertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 and 2 :

You need to capture the PointerPressed event of the ListItem, or in the DataTemplate of the ItemTemplate.

Then set the ReorderMode to Enabled :

```
        if (ListView != null && ListView.ReorderMode != ListViewReorderMode.Enabled)
        {
            ListView.ReorderMode = ListViewReorderMode.Enabled;
        }
```

Comment: this may work for 2 but I am sure it will not for 1, I do not see any code to setting the tap item to the foreground.

Comment: @IgorKulman I've been there, this can not be done out of the box.
The ReorderModeBehavior executes in the context of the selected ListItem, you can possibly create a Dependency Property on the Behavior (like the ListView Dependency Property) and let the datacontext know what item has been selected.

I figure that might work :)

Comment: yeah, 1 works fine with the repo, thanks, I think I can implement 2 using the comment about `ListView.Items.VectorChanged`, or do you have any better idea?

Comment: I'd handle the CollectionChanged event on the ViewModel, but if you need it in the UI. You're probably better off with VectorChanged.

Comment: ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset will not fix the issue since it only applies to the HintStates. I guess you'll need to create your own DropTargetItemThemeAnimation.